# Remove dash separated numbers from the end of string in Bash

Tags: bash

`XX-XX-XXXXX-ddd-dd-ddddd` is composed of two parts:

- `XX-XX-XXXXX` is composed of letters, it may contain one or multiple dashes, e.g. `abc-de-fghij`, and `abcde-fghi-j`.
- And `ddd-dd-ddddd` is composed of digits, again, it may contain one or multiple dashes, e.g. `123-456-7890`, `12-3-456-7890`.

What is an easy way to get the `XX-XX-XXXXX` in Bash? For example, suppose I have `abc-de-fghij-123-456-7890`, how do I get `abc-de-fghij`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%%` variant of parameter expansions, you can remove everything including and following the first dash that is immediately followed by a digit.

```
$ str=abc-de-fghij-123-456-7890
$ echo "${str%%-[0-9]*}"
abc-de-fghij
```

Comment: @ oguzismail: it works. Thank you very much!